# How to get call back response while having multiple same view controllers in the view in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, callback, delegates

Having 3 view controllers, same class but multiple objects.
Sending same call back to the three view controllers, not reaching to the visible view controller, only calling on the last view controller of the array.

Any suggestion, how to solve this.
I will appreciate your help, tried the Notification center, as you know these are calling multiple times, no proper handling.

This is callback handling

```
FileViewerDownloaderManager.shared.startDownload = { (model: ContentModel) in
            // Reload the cell
            self.refreshData(modelContent: model)
        }

        // Stop download
FileViewerDownloaderManager.shared.stopDownload = { (model: ContentModel, error: Error?) in
            self.refreshData(modelContent: model)
        }
```

Calling like this

```
startDownload(model)
```

This is my notification center code

```
func addWith(name: String, callback: escaping (Notification) -> Void) { 
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: 
     NSNotification.Name(rawValue: name), object: nil, queue: nil, using: 
     callback) 
}

 func removeWith(name: String, from: Any) {
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(from, name: 
         NSNotification.Name(rawValue: name), object: nil)
  }
```

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: I have updated the question, @UsmanJaved, please check.

Comment: Show your notification center code -- that should work.

Comment: @LouFranco, thanks, now with the nofication center, the same done.
Had this code

func addWith(name: String, callback: escaping (Notification) -> Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: name), object: nil, queue: nil, using: callback)
    }
    
    func removeWith(name: String, from: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(from, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: name), object: nil)
    }

I have updated the callback to the simple notification with the observer method.

Comment: And just called the add and remove method of notification center on the didAppear and didDisappear, working. But with the call back which I have added in the question, not working.

Comment: Please put the code in the question and format it correctly.